# MVC where should I validate my data?

Tags: zend-framework, validation, mv

I'm using the Zend Framework and I want to check that certain fields are not being submitted as null or empty. Where should I do this checking; model or controller?

Note, I'm not using Zend forms, I coded them in HTML and I take the contents using:

```
$this->_getParam('inputName');
```

I will be using js to check at the front end but it's easy to bypass js so I want some backend stuff as well.

Comment: You're talking as if the client validation is more important then the server side validation. DANGER. First comes a full set of server side validation then more server side validation and some more... then maybe for user convenience some client side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it really depends on how you design your application. Sometimes it is really important to validate data in your model, when it relies on business logic, but if you just want to check if a value is null or empty (and probably notice your user), then do it in your controller.

Since you wrote your form *manually* you may want to use [`Zend_Filter_Input`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) which will  help validate and filter your inputs.

```
$filters = array(
    'inputName' => 'StringTrim'
);

$validators = array(
    '*' => 'NotEmpty',
);

$inputFilter = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);

$inputFilter->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

if ($inputFilter->isValid()) {
    echo 'Congratulations!';
} else {
    echo 'Too bad :(';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you care is if your strings are non-null/non-empty, then you can simply do:

```
if ($this->_getParam('inputName')) {
   echo 'input name is not null or empty';
}
```

Note: a value of 0 will not pass this.
Although I would still recommend using the appropriate validation libraries.